# Django load text file into html file using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I want to implement this example code from [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load) using Django. The code loads a text file into a html file using the jquery `load()` function. The code looks like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is now, how do I store my text file such that the load function has access to it in my Django project?

Comment: You can simply upload the txt file to your server. The fact you're using Django isn't really relevant in this case. I'd also suggest caution when using W3Schools examples. They are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the 'demo_test.txt' in your static folder and make sure to specify your static url in settings. Let's say your static url is "cdn" pointing to folder "static". In that case you could use `$("#div1").load("/cdn/demo_test.txt");`

In `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/cdn/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/path/to/your/static'
```